# How can I centre the area that displays the question in my javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript, css

So I have an area in my js quiz where it displays the question. I would like to know how I can centre that area and put a box around it, to make it look fancy. Would be great if someone can help.
Thanks (code  and screenshot of the area I would like to be entered is below).

```js
// This initialises a request to the trivia database API
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "//opentdb.com/api.php?amount=25&category=21&type=multiple";
var score = 0;
var livesTaken = 0;
var question;
var type;
var correctAnswer;
var incorrect1;
var incorrect2;
var incorrect3;

// This requests the data
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    getData(jsondata);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

// This function is used to extract the received data
function getData(data) {
  // This is the question:
  question = data.results[0].question;

  // This is the question type eg. multiple choice
  type = data.results[0].type;

  // This is the correct answer
  correctAnswer = data.results[0].correct_answer;

  // These are the three incorrect answers
  incorrect1 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[0];
  incorrect2 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[1];
  incorrect3 = data.results[0].incorrect_answers[2];

  // randomly select answer and other options and place in array
  // then display elements from array on the buttons

  var randoms = []; // an array to store unique random numbers
  var random;

  // loop runs four times...
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // generates a random number between 0 and 3
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    // checks if random number already in array...
    while (randoms.includes(random)) {
      // generates another random number
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    }
    // adds random number to array
    randoms.push(random);
  }


  var options = [];
  console.log(randoms);
  options[randoms[0]] = correctAnswer;
  options[randoms[1]] = incorrect1;
  options[randoms[2]] = incorrect2;
  options[randoms[3]] = incorrect3;


  console.log(options);

  // This displays the question and answer options

  document.getElementById("trivia").innerHTML = question;

  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    let br = document.createElement("br");

    btn.classList.add("trivia-btn"); // We're adding the class here
    btn.setAttribute("onclick", `checkAnswer("${options[i]}", this)`);
    btn.innerHTML = options[i];

    document.getElementById("trivia").append(br, btn); // You can now use the trivia div as a container for the generated button and your br
    //document.getElementsByClassName("trivia-btn").disabled = false;  
  }
}

function checkAnswer(selected, element) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".trivia-btn").forEach((e) => {
    e.disabled = true
  });

  console.log("User selected: " + selected);
  console.log("The correct answer is: " + correctAnswer);
  if (selected == correctAnswer) {
    score++;
    console.log("You got it right!");
    element.style.background = "green";

    setTimeout(function () {
      getNewQuestion();
    }, 2000);

  } else {
    livesTaken++;
    console.log("Sorry, that's incorrect");
    element.style.background = "red";
    if (livesTaken == 3) {
      quizFailed();
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        getNewQuestion();
      }, 10);
    }
  }
  console.log(score)
  console.log(livesTaken)
}


function getNewQuestion() {
  document.getElementById("score").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("score").style.float = "right";
  document.getElementById("trivia").style.float = "left";
  document.getElementById("score").style.align = "right";
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "score:" + score;
  document.getElementById("trivia").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("endingText").style.display = "none";
  // This requests the data
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      getData(jsondata);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
getNewQuestion()

function quizFailed() {
  document.getElementById("endingText").style.display = "block"
  document.getElementById("score").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("trivia").style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById("endingText").innerHTML = "You have run out of lives, you scored " + score + " pretty bad ngl" + "  <button onClick = getNewQuestion() >click to restart</button>"

  score = 0;
  livesTaken = 0;
}


document.getElementById("score")
```

```css
.trivia-btn {
  background-color: "blue";
  padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sport.css">
    <title>Sport Quiz (Medium)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Sport.js"></script>
    <div id="trivia"></div>
    <div id ="endingText"></div>
    <div id ="score"></div>
    <div id ="exittext"></div>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

[I would like this to be centred in the middle of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWc9F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

[image: Centered all content]

If that is the case then you could simply change the styling of the trivia div by removing the float and adding `text-align: center;`. The only thing this would break is the positioning of your score.
That could be solved by adding this styling to the *#score* div

```
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
```

But without proper context that might clash with other things on your page?

If this is not what you meant, just let me know. :-)

Comment: It is thank you for your help, one problem this does not seem to work for me can u show what exactly I should remove?

Comment: Sorry I didn't referenced it too your actual code: the ```float: left;``` that needed removal was actually this line:
```document.getElementById("trivia").style.float = "left";```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this property `document.getElementById("trivia").style.float = "left";`
add this property `document.getElementById("trivia").style.textAlign = "center";`